# Ubuntu: Qt: Error: ‘class qbs::Project’ has no member named ‘addFiles' when building qt

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-16.04

I'm installing qt on ubuntu 16.04 (I can't upgrade the ubuntu version) through a guide provided by my colleagues. When installing qt I've followed a couple of steps:

> wget https://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/4.1/4.1.0/qt-creator-opensource-src-4.1.0.tar.gz

> tar zvxf qt-creator-opensource-src-4.1.0.tar.

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

> sudo apt-get install qt5-default

> cd qt-creator-opensource-src-4.1.0

> cd src

> qmake -r

> make

When running the command **make** I get the following errors:

**qbsproject.cpp:281:43: error: ‘class qbs::Project’ has no member named ‘addFiles’
qbs::ErrorInfo err = m_qbsProject.addFiles(productData, groupData, QStr**

**error: ‘class qbs::Project’ has no member named ‘removeFiles’
= m_qbsProject.removeFiles(productData, groupData, QStringList(**

I've already researched it and came up with this link: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20360?gerritIssueStatus=All

But I've already installed qbs and I don't understand what to do next.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you

Comment: Why do you not install kindly built qt creator for you https://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/4.1/4.1.0/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.1.0.run?

Comment: And why not a bit newer version https://download.qt.io/archive/qtcreator/4.4/4.4.1/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.4.1.run?

Comment: And why not the newest https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/5.0/5.0.3/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-5.0.3.run?